# lightbox opening html

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am trying to open a form using lightbox, the form itself is a html that is used in another page.

The problem is that I tried [ShadowBox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) and it opens an iframe, most of my variables are lost in the process. I tried `Lightbox5` and I can't seem to find code to pass in a html.

Any suggestions?

I did something like this with ShadowBox

```
<a rel="shadowbox[MyStuff]" href="survey.html">survey</a>
```

it will parse that the passed in element is a html, but it will open in an iframe thus losing the variables i have in this page

added the whole sample code

```
<html>

<head>
    <!-- the shadowbox stylesheet and js -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.lightbox-0.5.css"
    media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lightbox-0.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document)
            .ready(function ()
        {
            // Use this example, or...
            $('a[@rel*=lightbox]')
                .lightBox(); // Select all links that contains lightbox in the attribute rel
            // This, or...
            $('#gallery a')
                .lightBox(); // Select all links in object with gallery ID
            $('#somehiddendiv div')
                .lightBox(); // Select all links in object with gallery ID
            // This, or...
            $('a.lightbox')
                .lightBox(); // Select all links with lightbox class
            // This, or...
            $('a')
                .lightBox(); // Select all links in the page
            // ... The possibility are many. Use your creative or choose one in the examples above
        });
        $(function ()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: 'survey.html',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data)
                {
                    $('#somehiddendiv')
                        .html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- <a href="egypt.jpg"><img src="download.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" /></a>
-->
    <div id="somehiddendiv"></div>
```

```
</body>
```

Comment: Fetch the other page using an ajax call and populate the lightbox in the correct event?

Comment: sorry I don't quite get what you are saying.

Comment: @Johan, is it possible to help modify the sample code above?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: 'yourotherhtmlpage.html',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            $('#somehiddendiv').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Then add a link or whatever that opens the div in a lightbox window. Or open it by code.

Comment: sorry i am new to jquery and all. so i added at the pastebin what i can to add a link?

Comment: @jonleech Doesnt look like fancybox supports div popups, only iamges. Try using fancybox with this code

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) plugin for the same purpose

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* This is basic - uses default settings */

    $("a#single_image").fancybox();

    /* Using custom settings */

    $("a#inline").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': true
    });

    /* Apply fancybox to multiple items */

    $("a.group").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600, 
        'speedOut'      :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false
    });

});
```